# How to get rid of spaces around navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

recently I've been learning to style navbars and it is the most oddly difficult thing I've came across in my web development training. In this code I've my navbar almost styled but the problem is I'm getting a small white space on the right of the page. I'm confused as to which element might be causing this. I've tried everything padding, margin, border, nothing helped. I've looked at other answers on Stackoverflow, most of them suggested to add a "margin:0" to the entire body. To make matters even strange, I already have it in there.

Another thing I would like to add is that while coding for this project, I did encounter the white gaps problem many times, but I used a lot of "dirty coding" (for eg: adding margins or paddings to elements inside the navbar to make it look like the navbar is perfectly sticking to the top and to the sides while actually it isn't). Can someone please explain how do I get the navbar stick perfectly to the top and to the sides while also not having any of the "dirty code". Thanks in advance.

Also guys, since I'm just learning Web Development, my code might look like a complete mess because I don't know myself where is bootstrap applied and where I've Overriden it. Sorry about that.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <!-- META TAGS -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a2efd1781b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Stencil.io</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-collapse-md bg-dark">
        <h1>stencil.io</h1>

        <div class="row navbar-toggler">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.quora.com">Quora</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://youtube.com">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <header>
         <h1 class="title">All your social media at one place.</h1>

        <div class="icons container-fluid">
            <i class="snapchat fa-brands fa-square-snapchat fa-7x"></i>
            <i class=" instagram fa-brands fa-instagram fa-7x"></i>
            <i class=" twitter fa-brands fa-twitter fa-7x"></i>
        </div> 
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
     }

  nav{
    color: antiquewhite;
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
  }

  h1{
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  ul{
    list-style: none;
  }

  li{
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: antiquewhite; 
  }

  a:hover{
    color: #FFD39A;
  }

  .title{
    font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 150px 100px;
    float: left;
  }

  i{
    padding: 30px;
  }

  .icons{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;

  }
```

Adding an Image for reference:
[You Can see the small white gap in the right of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWhEG.png)

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools to see exactly who/what is adding CSS where? Also you say you have removed all the default margins, but I can't see anywhere you have done this, could you point it out? And try to make a runnable example see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Some other code that you added is causing the gap as the provided code by itself seems to be working fine as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/mtp6qkfu/2/

Comment: One has to debug this in browser, a screenshot is absolutely useless in this case. This is most likely styles from bootstrap but its impossible to point the problem with 100% accuracy just from this infromation. You have to provide exact copy of project and we will be able to offer a solution

Comment: Well I'm glad to inform you that getting rid of the "row" class overall fixed my problem. You can see in my stylesheet that I've added a "margin:0" and "padding:0" to the body to get rid of the default margins. Damien's answer over here helped a lot. Apparently the "row" bootstrap class has some of it's own annoying margins which causes these gaps. I haven't tried the other methods he suggested but I will soon, to clear any confusion when i encounter such problems in the future. Thanks Damien for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting on bootstrap's row class that has a sometimes annoying  `margin-left: -15px` and `margin-right: -15px`. So you have three solutions :

1- Overriding Bootstrap's row class :

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
}
```

2- Wrapping your `.row` div in a `.container-fluid` div (But you might have to change your nav)

3- Best way : Get rid of your `.row` class (Not sure you need it here btw)

GLOBALLY : You might have to look into bootstrap structure to have a better understanding of how it works. Rows should always (well, nearly) be wrapped in a `container` or `container-fluid` in Bootstrap. Missing it is what generally causes this type of horizontal scrolling caused by negative margins on the `.row` as explained at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 0):

this might work for you

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.